# MySQL 8 InnoDB Partitioning - Maximum Number of Partitions

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, partitioning

> What is the maximum number of partitions for InnoDB storage engine in
>   MySQL 8?

If I remember well it used to be 1024 but that was prior to MySQL 8.

I Would like to know whether it is changed in MySQL 8?

[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations.html) does not mention any limit for InnoDB, only 8192 for the NDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations.html

> **Maximum number of partitions.**  The maximum possible number of partitions for a given table not using the NDB storage engine is 8192. This number includes subpartitions.

"Not using NDB storage engine" means InnoDB, and other engines. Just not NDB.

P.S. It's amazing how often readers overlook the word "not" in writing. Don't take this as a personal criticism -- lots of people do it.